# Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server localhost can't be contacted via RPC. Error 0x6D9

Tags: exchange

I have Exchange installed and the certificate verified.

On a computer in Network I can send out emails but can not receive them.

On a computer outside the network I am not send or receive.

When I attempt to go https://mail.advsystems.com/owa/

I am given the following error.

The Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server localhost can't be contacted via RPC. Error 0x6D9.

Comment: This reads like a firewall issue.

Comment: We have no outisde firewall. Just Exchange, 2 Domain Controllers and a Gateway Server.

Comment: The Exchange Server's firewall is the one I meant. And honestly, you should have at minimum a firewall between the public internet and the LAN.

Comment: How do I configure the Exchange Firewall. Once I am getting mail my exchange account then I will look at external firewalls

Comment: @Davidw for testing I turned the firewall off.

Answer (score 1):

What’s your current Exchange version? How many users meet this issue?

Since you mentioned that can't send/receive messages on external network, make sure that you have enabled Outlook Anywhere.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/7806a15e-7b8c-4ef5-86da-cf6a3503f74f/off-site-users-unable-to-connect-all-the-sudden-to-exchange-2010-enviroment?forum=exchangesvrclients

Comment: 2019 all 4 of them.